# 'remote add' in netbeans 7.4?

Tags: netbeans, github

I am working on a fork that I created from a project on Github. I now want to merge changes in the project to my fork, using netbeans.

I read on [this page](http://www.eqqon.com/index.php/Collaborative_Github_Workflow) that I need to "remote add" the project to my list of remotes.
However, I cannot find a menu command to do so. Is there one?

In case there is not:

I can of course start a new netbeans project with the main project instead of the fork. But what is the best practice to merge those two then?

Answer (score 1):

In NetBeans 7.4 it looks like you can't just click "remote add" from a menu. It seems you can persist a new remote if you click Remote -> Push and go through the wizard. See also: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=191540